# Installing wkhtmltopdf in CentOS 6 x64

Tags: centos

I have downloaded the package like this

```
wget https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

but when I run the installation command

```
tar -xvzf wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2 -C /opt
```

I get the following error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decompress the file using the **j** option:

```
tar -xjvf wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2 -C /opt
```

The **j** option is used to decompress and extract the contents of the compressed archive created by [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/) program (files which extension is `tar.bz2`).